# Changing package path from existing imported project

Tags: android, package, settings

How can I change the entire package path in Android Studio, so that also the import statements within Java classes and xml files will be changed automatically.

I know there are threads already posted about this topic, but whenever I change package path, I have to adapt all import statements by hand. And it's much work when there are over 100 classes :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your Java classes to different package, in Android Studio you can right click on package name and then select Refactor->Move.